# "Pop index out of range" for deck of cards

Tags: python, playing-cards

What I currently have is code to build a deck of cards, to shuffle the deck, and to build a hand from that deck.

```
from random import randint

def make_deck():
    deck = []
    for suit in suits:
        for rank in ranks:
           deck.append((suit,rank))
    return deck

suits = ['spades','hearts','diamonds','clubs']
ranks = ['ace','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','jack','queen','king']

deck = make_deck() #list of cards

def shuffle(deck):
    for k in range(100): # do it 100 times
        card = deck.pop(randint(0,51))
        deck.append(card)

def make_hand():
    hand = []
    for k in range(2):
        card = deck.pop(randint(0,51))
        hand.append(card)
    return hand

hand = make_hand()
```

When I run the program, printing `deck` will give me the list of cards as I like and then when I try to shuffle the deck, I get an error stating that the pop index is out of range. Not quite sure why it would be out of index since the range (0,51) represents all 52 cards of the deck.

The same error shows up when I try to use the `make_hand()` function, though not always. Am I using the `pop` method incorrectly? What do I have to change so that the `shuffle` function works and the `hand` will always return two different cards from the deck?

Comment: As another answer points out, you're not adding cards back after making the hand, I assume this is intentional behaviour but are you forgetting to rebuild the deck before reshuffling the cards? It would help to show the flow of how these get called.

Comment: Are you sure your deck really has 52 cards?  (Try: print len(deck) after you call make_deck().)  There's a problem with the formatting in your code - the two 'for' loops don't work as shown because of the indentation. I wonder whether you're returning from the wrong place.  (When I fix the indentation of the second 'for' and run it myself, I get no errors.)

Comment: Oh wow. The deck only has 50 cards. Now I'm even more confused! (Also, the indentation is correct on my own, I just didn't format it correctly when I was copying it onto SO.)

Comment: the deck has 52 cards upon creation. Just put `print len(deck)` right after `deck = make_deck()`

Comment: I did, it returns 50. It seems to be missing different cards each time. The first time i looked at the list, it is missing a king of hearts and three of clubs and the second time, I see that it's missing a five of diamonds and some other card.

Comment: I've mistaken, the deck does have 52 cards. (Realized I was including the `make_hand()` function.) So a deck with 52 cards should not be out of range for the `shuffle` function, no?

Comment: @ChartererSling yes. Moreover. i've tried to call `shuffle` function right after `make_deck` and there were no problems with it. I can not reproduce it.

Comment: @ChartererSling also I should note, that suggestion to use `shuffle` from `random` module is a solid advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safer to write this as

```
card = deck.pop(randint(0,len(deck)-1))
```

Though it's faster if you save that value somewhere.

But that also points to a problem that your deck has a problem. Are you for loops in the deck creation formatted correctly? It's possible that you're creating less than 52 cards and so when you generate an integer on the high end you're catching that error. This also seems likely if it occasionally happens in make_hand (where you iterate twice) and constantly in shuffle (where you iterate 100 times).

If your intention is to shuffle cards after hands were dealt, then you definitely need to be using len() or keeping track of the deck size some other way. And even in the make_hand function, you're popping one card and then still trying to draw from a list of size 52 even though you've taken a card out.

Comment: Hmm, I think I've fixed the problem with make_hand, I can see now why there may be a case where the index is too high if a card is being taken out  of the deck from the first iteration (i.e. only 51 cards left after the first pop). From what I can see, the for loops in `make_deck()` are right--simply creating a list of suit and rank combinations, 4 suits and 13 ranks so 52 combinations.

Comment: What order do the functions get called in? It's possible that you're not fully accounting for a change in the deck.

Comment: The order of the functions is `make_deck()` and then `shuffle(deck)`. This returns the pop index error. The `shuffle(deck)` should be in range because when created, the deck has 52 cards.

Comment: It definitely should have 52, try adding print statements to keep track of the size as it changes, see if there's a leak somewhere (though I can't see why there would be)

Comment: It appears that the deck actually only has 50 cards. Ran it twice and when scanning over the list of the deck, it seems that there were different missing cards each time the function was called.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that the deck returns 50 cards because I call on `make_hand()` in he main program.

Comment: Aha! That'd be it then. As I said it's probably best to check the size each time you run shuffle to avoid that. If you need to use the function in multiple contexts you'll have trouble like this.

Answer (score 4):

`pop` mutates the list by removing the item from the list. So, the list's length will become less than `52` and an error will eventually be thrown. Instead of `51`, use the list's length each time `len(deck)`.

For the shuffling, you could also used a function `shuffle` from the library `random`:

```
from random import shuffle
## later in the code 
shuffle(deck)
```

Comment: but OP adds card back to the deck right on the very next line of `shuffle`

Comment: No, he doesn't in the `make_hand` function.

Comment: Well, you didn't address the problem with `shuffle`;). Also I assume, that removing cards from the deck in `make_hand` is not a mistake, but intentional behaviour

Comment: Hmm, yeah I removed that answer, after I understood I made a mistake, I'll also add shuffle then. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't intend on adding the card back into the deck because there's a possibility that the second card will be the same card. Instead, I have changed is so that there's a `card1` and `card2` with different ranges for the deck.

Comment: Yeah, I removed that part of the answer, but using the len(deck) is a safe way to go and you won't have to modify that function at all, except removing `51` and adding `len(deck)`. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, but I got carried away but the previous function where you were adding the card back.

Answer (score 1):

In `make_hand`, you take 2 cards out of the deck. The first one will always succeed, but the second one has to work with a deck that contains only 51 cards, while there's still a 1 in 52 chance of trying to `pop(52)`, which will fail.

I can't reproduce the same error with the `shuffle` function, unless I pass it a deck that has been used in `make_hand` first, so I'm assuming that's what you did as well.

Just to be sure, you could use `randint(0, len(deck)-1)` in both functions.